# Correct login process

Tags: session, cookies, authentication, sha1

I haven't had to tackle a login process before so this is new territory for me and all I seem to be finding on Google are conflicting methods of handling this process, so I was hoping someone could help clarify.

So far I have a salted SHA1 hash made from mixing username, password and my salt variable.
When the user logs in their credentials get hashed, then this hash gets sent to sql and if found comes back with a UserID (or something). So I know they are authenticated.
With that I can handle their session with session variables.

Is that right so-far?

Anyway, I wanted to have the option of "remember me" and was looking at storing something in a cookie but am not sure what to put in there as, as-far-as I am aware storing the hash would be pretty much the same as putting their username & password in plain text.

I'm confused, can anyone shed some light?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are usually better off using the authentication methods provided by your platform than creating one yourself.  There are a lot of non-obvious problems that you can easily leave yourself open to.  Which platform are you using?  Are you using a web framework?

General purpose hashes like SHA1 are inappropriate for password hashing as they are optimised to be very quick, when you want something that is very slow.  For discussion of this, see [How To Safely Store A Password](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).

> Anyway, I wanted to have the option of "remember me" and was looking at storing something in a cookie but am not sure what to put in there as, as-far-as I am aware storing the hash would be pretty much the same as putting their username & password in plain text.

Hashes are designed to be one-way functions, so no, it isn't the same as putting their username and password in plain text.  However if you do it that way, you'll have to create a way of letting somebody authenticate with the hash instead of their username and password, and *that* is the same as storing their username and password on the client (as far as you are concerned, anyway).

Comment: who sais he has got a platform? looks like he wants to code himself. further more most provided login processes by frameworks are crappy because they focus on other stuff.

Comment: His platform is what he is building on top of.  Everybody uses a platform, even if you completely scrap even the web server and write C communicating with browsers through raw sockets, you're still on top of an OS.

Comment: Most framework or platform-provided authentication systems are higher quality than things people invent by themselves.  They've had the chance to be put into production use, they've had multiple people working on them.  It's less likely that basic mistakes will be present.  Reinventing the wheel, particularly when it comes to security, is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Valid statements. Doesn't change the fact that imo most implementation in standard business frameworks don't fullfill todays requirements

Comment: The thoughts about sha1 are very valid. However a big tradeoff is that the login process also slows down YOUR server. Of course if your database and source code gets leaked you will be happy to have chosen bcrypt over sha1.

Comment: Right now, the only thing he has is hashing and cookies.  Which frameworks don't support those?

Comment: The performance impact of the speed of hashing routines is negligible for just about everybody smaller than Google or Facebook.  We're talking about a fraction of a second per *session*.  And using something like bcrypt lets you scale the security/performance tradeoff where you see fit, instead of being stuck at the insecure end with no choice.

Comment: Yeah, thats what he has now. But that way not suffices. And cookies and and hashing is not a user management component of any framework.

Comment: Imo bcrypt is fighting fire with fire. In the end it stays the exact same issue. And login validation IS a major point that acn occour often. Of course you can only do it at first hit during a session and then sue session validation. But most websites today have only 3-5 page impressions per user. Session lifetime is mostly somethin glike 25 minutes. If you rely on security by using a slow hashing function this can have a severe impact on your application. Better is keeping an eye on your database and not let it leak.

Comment: User authentication is omnipresent in frameworks.  Django, Pyramid, Zend, Symfony, Cake, ASP.NET... they all have authentication modules that you can use without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: *"Imo bcrypt is fighting fire with fire. In the end it stays the exact same issue."*  I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: *"But most websites today have only 3-5 page impressions per user."*  Not websites where people log in.  Do you honestly believe that authentication accounts for up to 33% of page views for typical websites?

Comment: *"If you rely on security by using a slow hashing function this can have a severe impact on your application."* This is not true for the vast majority of websites.  We're talking about a fraction of a second per session.

Comment: *"Better is keeping an eye on your database and not let it leak."* Crossing your fingers is not a valid security measure.

Comment: Wow, thank you all. I've opted for this method for the time being due to time constraints although I'm going to try Joe Hopfgartner's route at a later date because I'm having issues cancelling persistent cookies (server-side).

Answer (score 1):

I like the fact that you have used salt for your hashing but I don't think it's necessary to use the username for hashing only password+salt should be enough. Specially it will inflict an overhead of rehashing if you want the option of changeable usernames for your system.

For remember me option, I don't think you should store any credentials at client side cookies. Only the session ID should be enough. If you want to make it really secure you should use client-side certificates that are issued by the server.

http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/securitymonkey/howto-securing-a-website-with-client-ssl-certificates-11500

Comment: good point with the over salting. however storing sessino cookie is a problem because you need to reference them server side. this makes problem with durability and scalability as well as performance. see my answer for a nicer solution.

Comment: If you're going to use only password + salt, it needs to be a different salt for each user. Using a single salt still leaves you vulnerable to rainbow table attacks. You can store that salt in the database with the username - it doesn't need to be secret.

Comment: @Tom Anderson I didn't mean to store the same salt for all usernames. What I meant was that you don't need to include username value in creation of hash i.e. instead of MD5(username+pass+salt) use MD5(pass+salt) of course each user has different salt associated with its account inside the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your first login process is correct and up to todays security standards with the only exception that you may want to choose another hashing function over sha1.

Sha1 is very quick and therefore brute force attacks to crack a hash are faster. So if your hashes (database) and token (source code) get leaked, the passwords can be cracked.
One countermesure is to use a slower hashing function (see Jims answer for an article about that)

But the best of course would be not to leak your hashes in the first time.

A possibility for the remember me function is to let the user keep the session cookie for longer. For example Magento and Zend Auth does this.

This is however very ugly because you are likely to get hundrets of thousands of sessions stored on your servers, even for users that never return.

The far more elegant way is to store this information client side.

Sidenote: Of course you shouldnt put too many cookies on the client because they get transmitted with every page request. But a login cookie is a very valid case to do so. A good practice is to store the login cookie at the client side and populate the server session with data saved in a database at login which is marked in a session. This way you eliminiate continous database requests and have a good user data registry. Of course write has to be done to the database and session directly or better to the database and then somehow flushed to the application (full or incrementally).

Putting the hash in a client cookie isnt like "plaintext". However its ugly and awful and insecure on many levels.

There are some different approaches but they mostly involve some hashing again.

The most common and easy one is something like to put a cookie with `user_id=john` and `user_token=HASH($userid.$appsecret)` on the client. Or to store them as one in one cookie.

This is kinda secure but I prefer the following method:

Generate a string that holds:

```
userid ; user agent ; first two ip segments ; current timestamp ; your application secret token
```

Run it through a good hashing function and store a cookie at the users client that looks like

```
auth=userid;timestamp;hash-of-the-above
```

When the client logs in via cookie you re construct taht string from above but take the timestamp and user id from the cookie. Generate the hash and see if it matches. Then you have validated that it is the cookie you generated for that ip adress segment and this user agent at the specified time

Sidenote: first two ip segments rarely changes with dynamic isps. you can leave them away too, its for extra security.

What is the main advantage of thsi method?

The client or you can invalidate all login cookies by setting a timestamp. Only cookise that have been generated afterwards are accepted. You can also implement a timeout.

This is good if you want to "remote  logout" form a public computer where you forgot to log out or something.

I think functionality is very important and with this method you dont have to keep track of single login cookies (like google does).

Hope this helps you.

You can scale this method to any level of security you like and adjust it to your needs.

Comment: @Joe: I downvoted for your first sentence.  SHA1 is inappropriate for hashing passwords, so telling him that everything is fine is harmful.

Comment: i adapted my answer @Jim. Could you explain/reference the weakness of sha1 and name an alternative?

Comment: @Joe: You've still got that first sentence.  I'll include more information in my answer about the weaknesses of general purpose hashes.  MD5 is just as poor as SHA1 in this respect.

Comment: @Jim adpatd it again. did i even understand your concernss correctly?

Comment: No.  You don't understand the requirements of a hashing function, you downplay its importance, and you make the biggest mistake in cryptography.  Never, *ever* suggest to a beginner that they write their own cryptographic functions.

Comment: @jim @joe I think this method is not secure enough. Because if you do a simple man-in-the-middle replay attack, then you can acquire the session of the client. To put it simply if a malicious node sits between client and server and downloads the string that was intended to the honest client at the first place and resend it to the server, then it can impersonate the client. What do you guys think? I think the a very reliable method is using client side certificates as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: "But Chief, what if someone STEALS your certificate?"

Comment: @amirmonshi: Yes, MITM attacks are a problem for anything that doesn't use TLS.  However TLS solves this issue regardless of whether client-side certificates are implemented or not - there's nothing stopping you from using a "traditional" cookie-based approach over HTTPS.

Comment: @jim I don't think TLS can resolve this issue if client-side certificates are not implemented. Because then, only the traffic sent from client to server is encrypted. Still if the server wants to identify that whether the session is really coming from the real client is an issue that is generally solvable by client certificates. I explained that in the previous response because I think all this hashing in Joe's method doesn't really provide so much security because it is equal to sending a random session ID that is associated with the client on the servers-side if it can be replayed

Comment: @jim "all the hashing" as you call it is not intended to provide security but to be a efficient and solid way to fulfil the questioners requirements by not LOOSING security. as mentioned in my answer its absolutely possible to keep all session ids. but that comes with a trade of as also mentioned in my answer (hundrets of thousands of session files and problems when scaling and durability problems).

Comment: @amirmonshi: TLS encrypts both ways.  You don't need client certificates for the HTTP response to be encrypted.

Comment: @Joe What is "LOOSING security" exactly? If I understand you correctly you intend "almost secure". And if that's what you mean, your method still fails to provide it's purpose in that regard. Because, if malicious node can replay an ID string and get away with it, it doesn't make any difference if the content of the message is a human readable ID or something that is hashed with the best hash algorithm. In terms of performance I think your method sacrifices computational complexity(Hashing) severely for space complexity. That's also an idea.

Comment: @Jim yes you are right. But what I mean to say was server side certificates are used for encryption of the traffic and can not be used for identification of clients for periods longer that a TLS handshake session. When they reconnect, client can authenticate itself with its certificate.

Comment: and where does it fail? and where is yuor method useful? i think your method is rubbish because its a complete mess to maintain all the sessions and its also over complicated for a user to set up some client certificate.

Comment: @Joe First of all it's not my method. Second, there is no need to keep any session at the server-side. When the client identifies itself to the server it sends its certificate along the encrypted data. Server checks whether the certificate is signed by itself or not. Then it authenticate the userID from the certificate. Your method creates a hash that does not have any advantage over a random unique ID in terms of security and it can be replayed easily by MITM. You use this method to prevent ID theft but...

Comment: I know how signed certificates work. but how would you implement this in a website login? so that the process just works for the user by clicking a "remember me" box? Where would you store the private keys?

Comment: @Joe that's your assignment;)

Comment: i can think of multiple ways. but i don't see any advantage. i considered the following cases: 1. client cookie gets stolen and needs to be invalidated 2. database / source code gets leaked, clients passwords need to be protected 3. attacker tries to guess the right hash/code/password to log in - this should be slow and hard

Comment: @Joe 1. how can client cookie be stolen when there is two-ways encryption? I thought you understand cryptography. Oh sorry maybe you meant someone come to your house and put a gun against your head and says "Come on, copy your cookie to this flash" in that case he might as well ask for your password. 2. This is not even in the scope here because we are talking about communication security 3. LOL! Just one question have you even majored in a computer related field in university?

Comment: that is exactly what i mean. the world is much bigger than your isolated view. a usable solution needs to take all factors into account and still be compatible with todays user behaivour. which means everything needs to work for everyone automatically. of course i can ask everyone to send me their public key over a 2nd secured channel or something. but this is NOT RELEVANT!! so come on shoe me some code. some working step 1 - 10 manual that can be done in any language, works with every webserver and only requries the client to tick a checkbox!

Answer (score 0):

your authentication is just fine. If you want to make it even more secure you could transmit the login information with a SSL encrypted connection so nobody can read what's going across the network.

The remember token is quite simple let's say you want a remember me function that is valid for 14 Days.

A stranger with no authenticated session comes to your site:

1. Check if there is a remember me token in a cookie
2. If yes, check if you can find this remember me token in your database and check if the "valid until" column is still valid (date comparison)
3. If you find a valid token you can set the user id and authenticate his session
4. If you don't find a valid token redirect the user to the login page if necessary

When the user fills out the login form and authenticates him sucessfully:

Generate a token using an appropriate hashing function. The token you hash could look like "[Timestamp]---[userpwd]" so it's (almost) definitely unique! Save the token and the date until the token is valid (+14 Days from now as example) to your database connected with the user's id. If there's an expired token, replace it because you don't need to store expired tokens.

If the user logs out by clicking the logout button or similar just delete the token record in your database and the user's cookie.

That's it!

Comment: basically right but over complicated in my opinion. see my answer for a way that doesnt involve storing cookies in database.

Comment: +1 for mentioning https, something that is often forgotten while other mind blowing complicated methods are applied :)

Answer (score 0):

If your platform (web server etc) supports [HTTP digest authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617), i would strongly advise you to use it. It was designed by people who know more about security than either of us ever will. It doesn't send passwords over the network. It is supported by all modern web browsers, including mobile devices. If the browser has the password stored, it happens transparently during connection, giving you the 'remember me' functionality without needing to go anywhere near a cookie.

The only thing it doesn't do is let you use a nice form - the use will get a dialog box from their browser to log in.